# "Where did you read this?" as a reply to "I have read that ..."

Tags: tense-agreement

> **I have read** that...is...

Is 1 or 2 the correct reply to this?

1. Where **did you read** that?
2. Where **have you read** that?

Does the tense of the question change between asking it in a real-life conversation and replying with it in a chat after a while?

Comment: Either is acceptable. The thrust of the question is what was the source. There is no obligation to match the tense of the question with the tense of what triggered the question.

Comment: To me, a Canadian, 1. is more natural.

Comment: "Where have I seen that before?" sounds more natural than "Where did I see that?". Not sure why though.

Comment: I'm from the UK. Both of these look absolutely fine to me. There's no "correct" reply in my opinion. There is no rule in English which says a question must match the tense of something someone else has just said, but equally there's nothing to proscribe it either.